# Reload page after accepting error

Tags: javascript, php

I've got a PHP page that generates a javascript alert upon error.

```
    if (strpos($this->color,':') !== false) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Please use the RBG format of 255:255:255 for color.");</script>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">location.reload();</script>';
        die($conn); 
    }
```

As you can maybe surmise, I want to reload the page after I get the error, and not continue on with the rest of the PHP, which would actually insert the wrong data. The above causes an infinite loop after refresh and the alert continuing to pop up. How can I get the alert once, refresh the page, and keep going?

**EDIT**

Full code:

```
<!DOCspecies html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-species" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "kevin";
$password = "ally";
$database = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$getTableQuery = "SELECT tbf.Id, tbf.Name, tbf.Size, tbf.Color, tbs.Name as Species, tbs.Description
FROM tbl_fish as tbf INNER JOIN 
     tbl_species as tbs ON tbf.Species = tbs.Id
ORDER BY tbf.Id";

$table = $conn->query($getTableQuery);

if ($table->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Size</th><th>Color</th><th>Species</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $table->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["Name"]."</td><td>".$row["Size"]."</td><td>".$row["Color"]."</td><td>".$row["Species"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</br>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

if(isset($_POST['btnInsert']) && ($_POST['btnInsert'] == "Insert"))
{
    $Dog = new Dog($_POST['txtName'], $_POST['txtSize'], $_POST['txtColor'], $_POST['txtSpecies'], $_POST['txtDescription']);

    $Dog->InsertDog($conn);
}

class Dog
{
    private $name = "Dog Name";
    private $size = 0;
    private $color = "255:255:255";
    private $speciesName = "Species Name";
    private $speciesDescription = "Species Description";

    public function Dog($name, $size, $color, $species, $description){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->size = $size;
        $this->color = $color;
        $this->speciesName = $species;
        $this->speciesDescription = $description;
    }

    private function ColorCheck($color){
        if($color > 256 || $color < 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public function InsertDog($conn){
        $this->speciesName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->speciesName);
        $this->speciesDescription = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->speciesName);
        $this->name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->name);
        $this->size = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->size);
        $this->color = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->color);
        $_SESSION['reloaded'] = false;
        $color = explode(':', $this->color);

        if (strpos($this->color,':') !== false && !isset($_SESSION['reloaded'])) {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Please use the RBG format of 255:255:255 for color.");</script>';
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">location.reload();</script>';
            die($conn); 
        }

        if(!$this->ColorCheck($color[0]) || !$this->ColorCheck($color[1]) ||!$this->ColorCheck($color[2]) && !isset($_SESSION['reloaded'])){
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Please use the RBG format of 255:255:255 for color.");</script>';
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">location.reload();</script>';
            die($conn); 
        } 

        $speciesId = "SELECT Id from tbl_species WHERE Name = '$this->speciesDescription'";
        $speciesInsert = "INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_species (Name, Description) 
                                        VALUES ('$this->speciesName', '$this->speciesDescription')";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $speciesInsert) or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error($conn));

        if($id = $conn->query($speciesId)){
            $row = $id->fetch_assoc();
            $intId = $row['Id'];
        }

        $DogInsert = "INSERT INTO tbl_fish (Name, Size, Color, Species)
                             VALUES ('$this->name', $this->size, '$this->color', $intId)";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $DogInsert) or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error($conn));

        unset($this); 
    }

    public function UpdateDog(){
    }
}
$conn->close();
?>

<body>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
    Dog Name:<br />
    <input name="txtName" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    Size:<br />
    <input name="txtSize" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    Color:<br />
    <input name="txtColor" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    Species Name:<br />
    <input name="txtSpecies" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    Species Description:<br />
    <input name="txtDescription" style="width: 419px; height: 125px" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    <input name="btnInsert" type="submit" value="Insert" />
    <input name="btnUpdate" type="button" value="Update" />
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have to go back to the page where the user has the chance to select or change the value for color.

Comment: Can you show more of the code on this page? It would help to see how a fix would best fit in with what you've already got.

Comment: @mopo922: I added my whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location.reload` is just like hitting the "refresh" button in your browser, which means that the form will re-post and you'll go right back into this block every time:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnInsert']) && ($_POST['btnInsert'] == "Insert"))
{
    $Dog = new Dog($_POST['txtName'], $_POST['txtSize'], $_POST['txtColor'], $_POST['txtSpecies'], $_POST['txtDescription']);

    $Dog->InsertDog($conn);
}
```

Use this instead, as it will be more like a clean page load:

```
window.location = window.location.href;
```

Comment: Where would I add that? Also, I'm not really worried about a a reload per se. I just want it to not continue on with the PHP after the error. And at the same time, reload upon a successful insert.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks use that in place of `location.reload()`

Answer (score 0):

You could set a session to watch for reload. for example:

```
if (strpos($this->color,':') !== false && !isset($_SESSION['reloaded'])) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Please use the RBG format of 255:255:255 for color.");</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">location.reload();</script>';

    //set session
    $_SESSION['reloaded'] = true;

    die($conn); 
}
else
{
    //unset session so you can validate again. could be placed somewhere else
   unset($_SESSION['reloaded']);
}
```

Same could be done with a cookie.